# Is this a join, can we optimize this query?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is about a select query which looks like doing 2 selects on a Table and then doing a subquery on the result to find final output.

```
WITH TABLE1 AS
  (SELECT ID
   FROM SERVICE_INSTANCE TABLEA
   WHERE TABLEA.U_VC_NAME_NORM = ?)
SELECT ID,
       U_VC_SERVICE_TYPE AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_4,
       U_VC_VLBR_PERMANENT_URL AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_15,
       U_VC_CLOUD_ACCOUNT_ID AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_9,
       U_VC_ENTITLEMENT_ID AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_12,
       U_DT_REPLICATED_DATE AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_33,
       U_VC_NAME AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_1,
       ID AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_20,
       U_VC_IDCS_TENANT_GUID AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_5
FROM SERVICE_INSTANCE TABLEA
WHERE TABLEA.MAPPING_PATH = ?
  AND EXISTS
    (SELECT ID
     FROM TABLE1
     WHERE TABLEA.ID=TABLE1.ID)
```

I think this can be replaced by

```
SELECT ID,
       U_VC_SERVICE_TYPE AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_4,
       U_VC_VLBR_PERMANENT_URL AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_15,
       U_VC_CLOUD_ACCOUNT_ID AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_9,
       U_VC_ENTITLEMENT_ID AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_12,
       U_DT_REPLICATED_DATE AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_33,
       U_VC_NAME AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_1,
       ID AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_20,
       U_VC_IDCS_TENANT_GUID AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_5
FROM SERVICE_INSTANCE TABLEA
WHERE TABLEA.MAPPING_PATH = ? AND ID != NULL
```

Am I correct ?

Plan for first query is 
[image: Plan for First query]

Plan for second query is 
[image: Plan for second query]

Plan cost looks exactly same when tried with 5000 row or with <100 row.

Comment: `ID != NULL` doesn't do what you expect. You probably mean `ID IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

No, they are not the same.  This condition is not in the second query:

```
U_VC_NAME_NORM = ?
```

There may be some situations where they do the same thing, but that would be highly dependent on the data.

I suspect that the first query can be simplified.  However, your question needs sample data and desired results to help others to make sense of it.

Comment: True, sorry I missed the U_VC_NAME_NORM part in where clause.

Comment: If we change the where clause in 2nd query to WHERE TABLEA.MAPPING_PATH = ? AND TABLEA.U_VC_NAME_NORM = ? AND TABLEA.ID IS NOT NULL does it now equivalent to the first one, if I am not asking too much.

Answer (score 1):

No - It is however equivalent to;

```
SELECT ID,
       U_VC_SERVICE_TYPE AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_4,
       U_VC_VLBR_PERMANENT_URL AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_15,
       U_VC_CLOUD_ACCOUNT_ID AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_9,
       U_VC_ENTITLEMENT_ID AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_12,
       U_DT_REPLICATED_DATE AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_33,
       U_VC_NAME AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_1,
       ID AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_20,
       U_VC_IDCS_TENANT_GUID AS SERVICE_INSTANCE_ATTR_5
FROM SERVICE_INSTANCE TABLEA
WHERE TABLEA.MAPPING_PATH = ? AND TABLEA.U_VC_NAME_NORM = ? AND TABLEA.ID IS NOT NULL
```

As your CTE is checking U_VC_NAME_NORM = ?

Comment: Yeah thanks, I missed the U_VC_NAME_NORM part in 2nd query, does the first query looks like a join to you, a humble qstn ?

Comment: Yes - using WHERE EXISTS is equivilient to an inner join (providing there is only 1 row on either side, having more than one row that matches would obviously increase the number of rows in the result - but since the column is called ID I am assuming it is a key and therefore only one row matches the condition) as it will eliminate all rows which don't match the condition - However in this case the condition is simple (the U_VC_NAME_NORM) so you don't even need a join as it is in the same table, so you can just move the condition down into the where clause